# Formatting table to show a column name and the column text aligned

Tags: tables, columns

I am trying to unsuccessfully create a table. The second row namely "LET [ms]" and the column content (A,B,C,D) are not aligned. I added two "&" characters between the "Frame" and "LET [ms]" columns because otherwise column names are written one on the top of the other.[image]

```
 \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l *{7}{d{3.2}}}
                 \toprule
                            & & & 
                            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{U(P0)\textsubscript{frame}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{U(P1)\textsubscript{frame}}}

                            \\
            % Second Line
                         \cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
                         
                         \textbf{Frame} & &
                         \textbf{LET [ms]}
                         &
                 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Target}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Theory}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Target}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Theory}} &

                         \\
                         \midrule
                         
                         \hspace{1.5em} \cellcolor{lightgray} X & \hspace{1.5em} \cellcolor{gray} A  &  & 1.1 & 5.55 & 6.66 & .01  \\
                         \hspace{1.5em} \cellcolor{lightgray} Y & \cellcolor{gray} B & & 22.22 & 0.0 & 77.5 & .1  \\
                         \hspace{1.5em} \cellcolor{lightgray} W & \cellcolor{gray} C & & 333.3 & .1 & 11.11 & .05 \\
                         \hspace{1.5em} \cellcolor{lightgray} Z & \cellcolor{gray} D & & 4444.44 & 77.77 & 14.06 & .3 \\
                 \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}
        
        \caption{}
        \label{tab:Werte}
\end{table}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to make some guesswork regarding which packages you are using, but here is a working example. The problem was your preamble, where you had defined also the second column as a decimal aligned column, but filled it with letters. I defined the two fist column as centred columns and removed the extra column. Then i looks OK. I assumed your `d{3.2}` is a `D{.}{.}{3.2}` using the [dcolumn](https://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) package, but change it back to your use if I am wrong.

It also seems that you have defined one column more than necessary. You define seven columns, but only fill six of them with data. In example 2, I have corrected this, and then the heading in column three is also correct. If you prefer more space between column 2 and column 3, use a `!{\quad}` in the tabular preamble. In addition, column 1 and 2 look better if they are of the same width since you colourise them. You may use the new `\w`-columns to archive this, if you have an updated array-package on you system. A complete preamble will look like:

```
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{wc{1.5cm}}!{\quad} *{4}{D{.}{.}{3.2}}}
```

Have a look at picture 2 in example 2 below:

The command `D{.}{.}{3.2}` is syntax documented in [dcolumn](https://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn)'s manual, and means a math column (you need to feed in figures). The {.} is the decimal separator used for input and output. `{.}{,}` convert the decimal separator from full stop in, to comma out.

The command `*{2}{wc{1.5cm}}` means ‘two centred columns with a fixed width of 1.5 cm’. Alternative syntax is `*{2}{w{c}{1.5cm}}` and `w{c}{1.5cm}w{c}{1.5cm}`. If you want one more such column before the decimal aligned columns, you just change the number to `3` and add a `&` between the third and fourth column.

```
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{wc{1.5cm}}!{\quad} *{4}{D{.}{.}{3.2}}}
```

If you instead need a new seventh column at the end, just add

```
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{wc{1.5cm}}!{\quad} *{5}{D{.}{.}{3.2}}}
```

and add the `&` after the last column (before the `\\`), see example 2 picture 3.

Since you are using [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), you should *not* use vertical lines.

**Example 1 – seven columns**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn, array, booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{*{2}{c} *{6}{D{.}{.}{3.2}}}
                 \toprule
                            & & & 
                            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{U(P0)\textsubscript{frame}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{U(P1)\textsubscript{frame}}}

                            \\
            % Second Line
                         \cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}

                         \textbf{Frame} & 
                         \textbf{LET [ms]}
                         &
                 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Target}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Theory}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Target}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Theory}} &

                         \\
                         \midrule

                         \cellcolor{lightgray} X &  \cellcolor{gray} A  &  & 1.1 & 5.55 & 6.66 & .01  \\
                          \cellcolor{lightgray} Y & \cellcolor{gray} B & & 22.22 & 0.0 & 77.5 & .1  \\
                          \cellcolor{lightgray} W & \cellcolor{gray} C & & 333.3 & .1 & 11.11 & .05 \\
                          \cellcolor{lightgray} Z & \cellcolor{gray} D & & 4444.44 & 77.77 & 14.06 & .3 \\
                 \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}

        \caption{}
        \label{tab:Werte}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2 – six columns**

*Picture 1*

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn, array, booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{*{2}{c} *{4}{D{.}{.}{3.2}}}
                 \toprule
                            &  &
                            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{U(P0)\textsubscript{frame}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{U(P1)\textsubscript{frame}}}

                            \\
            % Second Line
                         \cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}

                         \textbf{Frame} & 
                         \textbf{LET [ms]}
                         &
                 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Target}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Theory}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Target}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Theory}} 
                         \\
                         \midrule

                         \cellcolor{lightgray} X &  \cellcolor{gray} A  &   1.1 & 5.55 & 6.66 & .01  \\
                          \cellcolor{lightgray} Y & \cellcolor{gray} B &  22.22 & 0.0 & 77.5 & .1  \\
                          \cellcolor{lightgray} W & \cellcolor{gray} C & 333.3 & .1 & 11.11 & .05 \\
                          \cellcolor{lightgray} Z & \cellcolor{gray} D &  4444.44 & 77.77 & 14.06 & .3 \\
                 \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}

        \caption{}
        \label{tab:Werte}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

*Picture 2*

[image]

*Picture 3*

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your working solution. And I am sorry that I forgot to write down the package I used. You assumed corectly I used `dcolumn` package.

Comment: I wonder if there are one more error in your table definition. Look at example 2

Comment: Yes, I was about to write you back. Thank you for the Example 2. This code works well. I am still trying to understand your code, namely `\begin{tabular}{*{2}{c} *{4}{D{.}{.}{3.2}}}`. So the 2nd part defines 4 columns which expect a number due to `{.}`? I tried to add the 7th column (not a multi-column) on the very right side. I appended of the above-mentioned code `\begin{tabular}{*{2}{c} *{5}{D{.}{.}{3.2}}}` (changed 4 to 5). However, I get the column 7th name displayed on the top of the 6th ("Theory").  I also do not understand how can I add vertical lines between columns in your code.

Comment: @SimpleThings See updated explanation in the answer.

Comment: If an answer is very good it must have a different score from zero in my opinion.